# Work out, phrasal verb

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

In [the article](http://www.english-test.net/lessons/5/index.html) I came up with a problem. I didn't understand the meaning of work out in the sentence:

> Now read the short story and try to **work out** what the expressions in
>   italics mean.

One of [the possible meanings](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/work-out#work-out__5) is

> to deal with a problem in a satisfactory way

But is doesn't quite fit in the context. I would say that in here it has a meaning similar to find out.

Can we use **find out** and **work out** interchargably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's closer to the definition of **figure out**

> to be able to understand something or to solve a problem

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/figure-out

Find out and work out have subtly different implications. Find out implies you just try to find the answer and don't care about the method. Work out asks you to go through all the steps of the method and come up with the answer yourself

Comment: So, [this](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/work-out#work-out__1) would fit here: _To solve a problem by considering facts_, right?